# Creating a xy scatter chart with many series using VBA

Tags: excel, vba

Hello I trying to create a xy scatter chart with many series. I have to pick every 8th column starting from column D as x axis value and every 8th column starting from column H as y axis value for each series. This has to be done upto end of number of filled (with value) columns in the sheet.
I tried making a code but this doesn't seem to work. Help is very much appreciated as I will have to do this for many sheets and files..
The code is below.
Thank you very much.

```
    Sub Macro2()
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim i As Integer
Dim j As Integer
Dim ws_count As Integer
Dim cht As Chart
Dim lCol As Long
Dim lRow As Long
Dim chtobjt As ChartObject
Dim rngChtData As Range
Dim rngChtXVal As Range
Dim xval As Range
Dim yval As Range
ws_count = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets.Count
MsgBox ("Total number of sheets" & ws_count)
For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
    'Find the last non-blank cell in column A(1)
    lRow = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, 5).End(xlUp).Row
    
    'Find the last non-blank cell in row 1
    lCol = ws.Cells(5, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

    MsgBox "Last Row: " & lRow & vbNewLine & _
            "Last Column: " & Columns(lCol).Address(False, False)
    MsgBox (lCol)
       
    ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart2(240, xlXYScatterSmoothNoMarkers).Select
    MsgBox (ActiveChart.Name)
    i = 4
    j = 1
    For i = 4 To lCol Step 8
    a = ws.Cells(5, i).Address
    a1 = ws.Cells(lRow, i).Address
    b1 = ws.Cells(lRow, i + 4).Address
    b = ws.Cells(5, i + 2).Address
    With ActiveChart.ChartArea
    .SeriesCollection.NewSeries
    .FullSeriesCollection(j).XValues = "=" & ws.Range(a, a1)
    .FullSeriesCollection(j).Values = "=" & ws.Range(b, b1)

    End With
    j = j + 1
    Next i
        
    i = i + 8
    
 Next



End Sub
```

Comment: The code is note getting pasted properly... the code starts in the body of the description of the request.

Comment: If you're using a For loop with `Step 8` you don't need the `i = i +8`